# How to find p-value from the Normal Distribution Table?

Tags: normal-distribution, p-value

I'm reviewing a Topic about "Meaning of the p value and confidence interval" they gave an example about "The Coin Tossing Experiment"
In the example I understand how to find "SE" and "The 95% confidence interval", but I don't understand how they find the P-Value in the Normal Distribution Table. They didn't give the table and didn't explain how to use the table.

[image: See Image]

I tried to find the P-value in the Table, but the table has two entries.

Comment: I don't think your question has anything to deal with R. But if it is please share your code or a reproducible example of what you have tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Welcome to SO - this seems like it should be a question for the course setter or administrator on Coursera - if the course does not provide the information or tell you where to find it, then you are likely not the only person having this issue.